# Why the Cocos2D programming guide suggests to use initWithTexture?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I found that in the [cocos2d Best Practices](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3asprites#speedup_sprite_sheet_loading_with_pvz) there is a suggestion to use initWithTexture to initialize sprite subclasses, instead in several books and tutorials I found that you can also use initWithSpriteFrameName. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the initialization methods in `CCSprite` use `initWithTexture:rect` to create the sprite.  For example,

```
-(id) initWithFile:(NSString*)filename
{
    NSAssert(filename!=nil, @"Invalid filename for sprite");

    CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: filename];
    if( texture ) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
        rect.size = texture.contentSize;
        return [self initWithTexture:texture rect:rect];
    }

    [self release];
    return nil;
}
```

Other functions (`initWithFile`, `initWithSpriteFrame`, `initWithSpriteFrameName`, et cetera) also call `initWithTexture:rect` either directly or indirectly.  If your `CCSprite` subclass has any special initialization that needs to take place (as it ostensibly will, since you're subclassing another class), doing it in `initWithTexture:rect` guarantees that it will be run.

Comment: I guess that also doing initWithSpriteFrame or those othe functions will, correct?